# Show thumbnail for a video url in angular js

Tags: angularjs, video

I am developing a site in angular js, i am uploading vimeo(https://vimeo.com/) or youtube video url. For this i have to show a thumbnail on my listing so is it possible to show preview of a video url using angular js.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using ng-repeat,

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'https://www.youtube.com/**'
  ]);
});

app.controller('videoController', ['$scope',
  function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.product = [{
      name: 'some name',
      description: 'some description',
      media: [{
        src: 'v5Asedlj2cw'
      }]
    },
    {
      name: 'some name 2',
      description: 'some description 2',
      media: [{
        src: 'v5Asedlj2cw'
      }]
    }
    ]
    
    ;

    $scope.getIframeSrc = function(src) {
      return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + src;
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="videoController">
  <div ng-repeat="media in product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="video-container">
        <iframe width="100%" ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(media.src)}}" frameborder="0 " allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```